# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method UserController

Tags: php

I created a login with the classes but gives me an error

> ( ! ) **Fatal error**: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   UserController::checkLogin() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\progettoPersonale\controllers\User Controller.php on
>   line 17
>
> ( ! ) **Error**: Call to undefined method UserController::checkLogin() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\progettoPersonale\controllers\User Controller.php on
>   line 17 Call Stack
>   # Time Memory Function Location 1 0.0010 360312 {main}( ) ...\login.php:0 2 0.0030 384208 UserController->__construct( )
>   ...\login.php:7

the two classes are:

```
class UserController
{
    public $username = '';
    private $logged   = false;
    private $usermodel = '';

    public function __construct()
    {   $this->usermodel = new UserModel();
        session_start();


        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset($_GET['action'])&& $_GET['action']== 'login' ){
            $username = (isset($_POST['username']))? $_POST['username'] :false ;
            $password = (isset($_POST['password']))? $_POST['password'] :false ;
            var_dump($password,$username);
            if ($username !=false && $password !=false && $this->usermodel->checkLogin( $username, $password )){

                $this->username =$username ;
                $this->logged = true ;

                $_SESSION['username']= $username ;
                $_SESSION['logged']= true ;
                $_SESSION[ 'message' ]  = 'Login effettuato correttamente';
            }else{
                $_SESSION[ 'message' ]  = 'Errore con il login; riprovare!';
            }
        }
        elseif (isset($_GET['action'])&& $_GET['action']== 'logout'){
            unset($_SESSION['username']);
            unset($_SESSION['logged']);
            $_SESSION[ 'message' ] = 'Logout effettuato correttamente';
        }
        elseif (isset($_SESSION['username'])&& isset($_SESSION['logged'])){

            $this->username = $_SESSION['username'] ;
            $this->logged = true ;
        }
        $this->redirectToProperArea();
    }
class UserModel
{
    private $dbconn = null ;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->dbconn = new DbConnector();
    }


    public function checkLogin($username, $password ){

        $newpassword =password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        $res=$this->dbconn->select(
            array('id_utente'),
            'iscritti',
            'nome_utente='.$username.'&& password='.$newpassword

        );
        $num_rows=$this->dbconn->num_rows($res);
        if ($num_rows ==1){
            return true ;
        }else {
            return false ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this an exact copy-paste from one single file? Because you are missing a `}` to close your `UserController` class.

Answer (score 1):

On line 17, you are calling `UserController::checkLogin()`, but the User Controller class has no method checkLogin. That function belongs to the UserModel class, so you must instead call `UserModel::checkLogin()`

Comment: The call is `$this->usermodel->checkLogin(..` and the previously-defined property `$this->usermodel = new UserModel();` should make this work fine